# Broken symlink to Vim

Tags: shell, vim, symlink, alias

I am trying to launch `vim`. I probably created a bad symlink to `vim`. I used `which` and `alias` commands to find out what is happening. Why doesn't it run `vim` properly?

```
MacBook-Air:~ miszo97$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
MacBook-Air:~ miszo97$ vim
-bash: /usr/local/bin/vim: No such file or directory
MacBook-Air:~ miszo97$ alias vim
-bash: alias: vim: not found
```

Comment: "I probably created bad symlink to vim"? Read your shell history and see *exactly* what you did do.

Comment: Are you sure that `/usr/local/bin/vim` is not just a hashed path? compare the output of `type vim` with that of `which vim` and execute `hash -d vim` if necessary.

Comment: also try running `/usr/bin/vim`, at least then we can be sure you actually have it properly installed. Then try `ls -l /usr/bin/vim`, if the first letter is `l`, you have overwritten your vim with a symlink somehow. Then show us what `echo $PATH` outputs and I guess double-checking if there is something fishy in /usr/local/bin/ won't hurt with `ls -l /usr/local/bin/vim`

Comment: I don't have Mac, but `brew install vim` to reinstall vim should capable fix automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
command -v vim
```

shows you how the shell currently handles the command `vim`.

In your case it is not an alias. It may be a shell function or it has been located at `/usr/local/bin/vim` earlier but you deleted the file or symlink.

If `vim` is somewhere else in your `$PATH` then you must make your shell realize the new location:

```
hash -d vim
```

If `vim` is not in your path then you have to either copy / move or link it there (and run `hash -d vim` if it is a different location) or create an alias, a shell function or a `hash` entry for it:

```
alias vim="/foo/bar/vim"
vim () { /foo/bar/vim ; }
hash -p /foo/bar/vim vim
```